# How to iterate through list inside Dictionary in Django Python

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, iteration

I have passed a dictionary who's structure is like

```
dic={'items':[1,2,3,4,5], 'price':[20,30,40,50,60]}
return render_to_response('somepage.html',dic)
```

from my template *somepage.htm* i want output to be like

```
1  20
2  30
3  40
4  50
5  60
```

What code should I write in *somepage.html* to get this output.

Comment: Did you read this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` first and then render it in your template:

```
dic={'items':[1,2,3,4,5], 'price':[20,30,40,50,60]}
dic['items_and_prices'] = zip(dic['items'], dic['prices'])
return render_to_response('somepage.html',dic)
```

Template:

```
{% for item, price in items_and_prices %}
    {{ item }}&nbsp;{{ price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is very concise, clean and is the **pythonic** way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
 dic={'items':[1,2,3,4,5], 'price':[20,30,40,50,60]}
 lista = []

 for i in dic["items"]:
     l = []
     l.append(i)
     lista.append(l)

 var = 1
 cont = 0

 for i in dic["price"]:
     lista[cont].append(i)
     var+=2
     cont+=1
```

Template:

```
    {% for i in lista %}
        {{ i.0 }}-{{ i.1 }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
```